# How do I get the number of nodes using terms from a vocabulary on the same line together the link to the term page?

Tags: views, 8, taxonomy-terms

I created a view of taxonomy terms, and then followed these steps to add the number of nodes using each term listed in the resulting view.

- As *Format*, I selected *HTML List* showing *Fields*
- As relationship, I added *Content using field_blog_category*, where *field_blog_category* is the field I added to a content type I created
- I checked *Use aggregration*
- I added *ID* (listed under the *Content* category) as new field
- I set *Aggregration type* to *Count* for the new field (by clicking on *Aggregration settings* for that field)

It works as expected, except the fields are not in the same line.

> [image: screenshot]

I checked the settings for both the fields, but I could not find a way to make them appear on the same line; even changing the settings for *Rewrite results* didn't help me.

Is it possible to have those two fields on the same line, without using *Table* as *Format*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. By default, a HTML List View displays fields wrapped in a couple of `DIV`s, a block-level element. Hence, it displays each field on a new line. To disable this, use the **Style Settings** > **Customize field and label wrapper HTML** checkbox for each field to use an element that isn't a block-level element (e.g. `SPAN`).

[image]

Comment: While using SPAN is the quickest & easiest way, just wanted to point out that you can also solve this with CSS [As DEMOED Here](https://jsfiddle.net/2tbh726d/16/)

Comment: You can use CSS for that too, but why would you use CSS styles when the Views module has already settings for achieving the same?

Comment: I think I found another way, but I don't remember which. I just remember it was a different setting.